# Unable to start keepalived

Tags: load-balancing, keepalived

I am trying to create load balancer using Virtual IP. I referred this link [Load Balancer using Virtual IP](http://support.severalnines.com/entries/23612682-Install-HAProxy-and-Keepalived-Virtual-IP-). After configuring by mistake I started the backup server's keepalived service first and then I started master server's keepalived. The problem is the backup server's keepalived is working fine but I can't start the master server's keepalived. I tried uninstall the keepalived and installed again but that didn't work.
Here is the config files

**Master Server**

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
   script "killall -0 haproxy"   # verify the pid existance
   interval 2                    # check every 2 seconds
   weight 2                      # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
   interface eth0                # interface to monitor
   state MASTER
   virtual_router_id 51          # Assign one ID for this route
   priority 101                  # 101 on master, 100 on backup
   virtual_ipaddress {
       192.168.0.54            # the virtual IP
   }
   track_script {
       chk_haproxy
   }
}
```

**Backup Server**

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
   script "killall -0 haproxy"   # verify the pid existance
   interval 2                    # check every 2 seconds
   weight 2                      # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
   interface eth0                # interface to monitor
   state MASTER
   virtual_router_id 51          # Assign one ID for this route
   priority 100                  # 101 on master, 100 on backup
   virtual_ipaddress {
       192.168.0.54            # the virtual IP
   }
   track_script {
       chk_haproxy
   }
}
```

**Output of Master Server while starting the keepalived service**

```
$ sudo service keepalived start
* Starting keepalived keepalived                                        [fail]
```

**Output of Backup Server while starting the keepalived service**

```
$ sudo service keepalived start
* Starting keepalived keepalived                                        [Ok]
```

Is anyone having suggestion what I am doing wrong here??

**Update according to comments:**
**Master Server Log:**

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep VRRP_Instance

Here it does not prints anything which mean that the keepalived does not start on Master server
```

**Backup servers log:**

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep VRRP_Instance
Mar 27 02:39:22 ubuntu keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Mar 27 02:39:23 ubuntu keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering to MASTER STATE
Mar 27 02:39:38 ubuntu keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Mar 27 02:39:39 ubuntu keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering to MASTER STATE
Mar 27 02:52:16 ubuntu keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received higher prio advert
Mar 27 02:52:16 ubuntu keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering to BACKUP STATE
```

Also one more thing after referring to a website I changed the state in keepalived.conf file of backup server to state BACKUP

Comment: and what do the log files tell you?

Comment: @natxo I updated the question please check edit.

Comment: check this site: http://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/12982.htm for debugging tips on keepalived. Something useful is to run the process on the foreground: keepalived -f /path/to/keepalived.conf --dont-fork --log-console --log-detail

Answer (score 0):

You have misconfigured your VRRP instance. You have `state MASTER` on both nodes, but you can have only one master. Set backup server to `state BACKUP` and it will work. In general, rules are quite simple:

Same on both servers:

- virtual_router_id - must be uniq for each group of servers
- virtual_ip

Different on both servers:

- Instance name ( vrrp_instance THIS-IS-INSTANCE-NAME { )
- state (MASTER on one, BACKUP on others)
- priority (uniq for each node, highest for master)

Comment: I can comment that I'm using keepalived 2. I establish in config file for three nodes as Master state for testing. The first node is working as master and when I execute systemctl restart keepalived for second and third nodes, it detects automatically that a Master node exists. Furthermore the second and third nodes are established as Backup state.

Answer (score 0):

`state MASTER` can only be set one of the node.
Alternatively, both set to `state BACKUP`, It will be automatically selected in MASTER by priority.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could repost your current config.  Maybe give this a try though.

Master server

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
   script "pidof haproxy"        # check the pid not kill it
   interval 2                    # check every 2 seconds
   weight 2                      # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
   interface eth0                # interface to monitor
   state MASTER
   virtual_router_id 51          # Assign one ID for this route
   priority 150                  # 150 on master, 100 on backup
   unicast_peer {
       <backup ip address>
   }
   virtual_ipaddress {
       192.168.0.54            # the virtual IP
   }
   track_script {
       chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

Backup server

All the same as the master but change:

```
state BACKUP
priority 100
unicast_peer {
     <master ip address>
}
```

ensure you are allowing VRRP protocol (IP proto 112) between master and backup.
Check state of each at /var/run/keepalived.INSTANCE.VI_1.state
Make sure haproxy starts before keepalived.